# Easily (as in WYSIWYG) customize the docbook output

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

I've used DocBook in the past and I love the idea behind the separation of content from presentation. I am very comfortable editing XML directly. In my extensive search to find the best documenting solution for my needs I am always coming back to this one solution:

DocBook -> Build system (ant, make, etc.) -> Output

I have seen lots of information concerning the best WYSIWYG, XML, Text editors for writing DocBook including alternative markup languages like asciidoc. All these solutions focus on the creation of DocBook or the nightmare of the DocBook tool chain. No one ever addresses the Output side other then to say "Just use XSL" or "Custom scripts"

When tasked to make a document or manual I don't want to worry about spending countless hours attempting to reprogram, customize, and modify the XSL, CSS, and shell scripts (i.e. O'Riely books). That is a very arduous task.

My query: is there a tool that makes the customizing easier? And is there anything that could be similar to say Pages or Word in that the user creates a template and the tool chain does the rest? Attempting to do a visual task like pretty logos and fixing all the broken layouts that the default XSL comes up with (pagination is a mess) is very difficult from a text editor. Content is easy. Editing DocBook XSL was truly a nightmare when I did it in the past. I've searched and I find lots of info on XML editors but nothing on XSL editors.

Or am I lacking a key understanding of the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a stylesheet.  CSS is more simple than you think so long as you stay from stupid crap like rounded corners, gradient backgrounds, and other irrelevance that you don't need.  Here is an example of an XML document that is beautified and tested cross browser:

http://mailmarkup.org/hcl/hcl1_0-documentation.xsd

Comment: Can you use a CSS when converting docbook to a print format such as PDF, ePub, RTF, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not what you are asking for but I've been using two CLI utils for simplifying my docbook toolchain: xmlto and publican.

Publican looks elegant to me but enough fitted for the Fedora & Redhat publication needs.

- https://fedorahosted.org/xmlto/
- https://fedorahosted.org/publican/